# Detecting "runs" of DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to detect runs of dom elements in jQuery?

For instance, if I have the following list of items

```
<ol>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
</ol>
```

Say I want to grab all the `li.foo` elements and wrap them inside their own `<ol>` block (or any wrapper for that matter) to end up with something like.

```
<ol>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="foo"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li><ol>
    <li class="foo"></li>
    <li class="foo"></li>
    <li class="foo"></li>
  </ol></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li><ol>
    <li class="foo"></li>
    <li class="foo"></li>
    <li class="foo"></li>
  </ol></li>
</ol>
```

As you can see from the example, I only want to wrap "runs" of `li.foo` dom elements (where there are 2 or more `li.foo` elements in succession.

I'm not sure of the best/most efficient way to accomplish this via jQuery (or just plain javascript for that matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kNfxs/1/

```
$('ol .foo').each(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    var nextUn = $th.nextUntil(':not(.foo)');
    if(!$th.prev('.foo').length && nextUn.length)
        nextUn.andSelf().wrapAll('<li><ol></ol></li>');
});
```

Loop over the `.foo` elements, and if the previous element is *not* `.foo`, and it has at least 1 `.foo` after it, then grab all the next `.foo` elements using the [`nextUntil()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method and include the original using the [`andSelf()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) method, then wrap them using the [`wrapAll()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method.

---

**Update:** *This will be a little more efficient because it avoids the [`nextUntil()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method when there's a previous `.foo()`.*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kNfxs/2/

```
$('ol .foo').each(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    if($th.prev('.foo').length) return; // return if we're not first in the group
    var nextUn = $th.nextUntil(':not(.foo)');
    if( nextUn.length)
        nextUn.andSelf().wrapAll('<li><ol></ol></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$(li).each(function(){
if($(this).next().hasClass('foo')){
---- Recursively check until the end of the run has been found ----
}
});
```

To recursively check write a function that checks the next element until the end of the run has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well this works for performance:

```
var $foo = $('.foo + .foo');
$foo.add($foo.prev());
```

$foo will be the set of "`.foo` runs"

Edit to add:

I thought of a simpler way:

```
var $foo = $('.foo + .foo').prev('.foo').andSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/v8GY8/

For posterity:

```
// Takes a jQuery collection and returns an array of arrays of contiguous elems
function groupContiguousElements( $elems ){
  var groups = [];
  var current, lastElement;
  $elems.each(function(){
    if ($(this).prev()[0] == lastElement ){
      if (!current) groups.push( current=[lastElement] );
      current.push( this );
    }else{
      current = null;
    }
    lastElement = this;
  });
  return groups;
}

var groups = groupContiguousElements( $('li.foo') );
$.each( groups, function(){
  var wrapper = $('<ol>').insertBefore(this[0]);
  $.each(this,function(){
    wrapper.append(this);
  });
});
```